# Why bigquery need higher tier level for similar queries

Tags: google-bigquery

all,
I recently use some UDF SQL in bigquery. Method 2 work in tier 1. And later I improve to use method 1, but then I noticed method 1 need higher Billing Tier than method 2:

method 1:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION newcolumn(col3)
...LANGUAGE js AS """
new_cols = {...}
return new_cols;
""";
SELECT col1, col2, newcolumn(col3).*
```

method 2:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION newcolumn(col1, col2, col3)
...LANGUAGE js AS """
new_cols = {...};
new_cols.col1 = col1;
new_cols.col2 = col2;
return new_cols;
""";
SELECT newcolumn(col1, col2, col3).*
```

I think method 1 is more efficient, but can not see why it need higher tier level? It is actually seems less effort needed. Any one has any idea why? Thanks

Zhihong

Comment: So the return type of both functions is the same? Can you share the actual JavaScript code? I wonder if it's possible to express it using SQL instead, which would be cheaper.

Comment: Hi, Elliott, thanks for your reply. Yes, both functions return the same json object. And method 2 include col1 and col2 as the parameter to the function, because I need them in the final table. Method 2 can run in tier 1 which is the same price as normal standard SQL. So that is not an issue. The col3 is a complex string with ';' delimiter like "var1=blaba;var2=blabla=blabla;var3=blabla,blabla;var4=...", which need be processed to get multiple new columns var1, var2, var3, var4 and so on.